# Best pratice for avoid business logic in view

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I'm using php 7.3 with laravel 5.7
I use a fields.blade.php for render same form for create and edit actions.

In form i have a select, and i'like avoid evict this conditional above in view. This role is because i set the $business only edit action

What the best pratice for remove this role? Move for a Helper? Move for a model method?

fields.blade.php:

```php
@php
if(isset($business)) {
  $collection = $business->categories()->pluck("name", "id");
}
else {
  $collection = [];
}
@endphp

{!! Form::select('category_id', $collection,  ['class' => 'select2'])  !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that conditional inside the controller and pass `$collection` to the view:

YourController.php

```
$collection = $business->categories()->pluck("name", "id");

return view('your.view', ['collection' => $collection]);
```

YourView.php

```
{!! Form::select('category_id', $collection,  ['class' => 'select2'])  !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider this too much business logic. Maybe you can rewrite it like this:

```
@if(isset($business))
  {!! Form::select('category_id', $business->categories()->pluck("name", "id"),  ['class' => 'select2']) !!}
@else
  ... optionally display info like "no business selected" or something ...
@endif
```

If the `$business` is not used otherwise you could also just pass the `$categories` from your controller.